# Swift - dynamically initializing nested structs

Tags: swift, struct, initialization, nested

I wanted to know if I can do what the title suggests.
Here is some code.

```
struct Crop {
    var name = String()
    var season = String()
    var reharvistable = Bool()

    //struct Stages:     
    struct Stage1{
        var minDay = Int()
        var maxDay = Int()
        var minWater = Int()
        var maxWater = Int()
    }/* 
    struct Stage2{
        var minDay = Int()
        var maxDay = Int()
        var minWater = Int()
        var maxWater = Int()
    } */
}

var Crops  = [Crop]()
var temp = Crop(name: "Turnip", season: "Spring", reharvistable: false)

Crops.append(Crop(Name: "Turnip", Season: "Spring", Reharvistable: 
     false,  Stage1(minDay: 2, maxDay: 3, minWater: 2, maxWater: 7)))
```

Stage 2 is commented out but I wanted to have up to Stage 6 in the future.

"temp" works but my attempt to add them to the array didn't. My ultimate goal is to have these "Crop"s to be store in an array, "Crops" so I want to be able to dynamically add more "Crop"s.
Also, the parentheses are after each datatype because they were giving me an error without them.

Answer (score 3):

How about instead of defining the stage structs inside your crop struct, you define them separately and have a stages array inside crop. Like this:

```
struct Crop {
    var name = String()
    var season = String()
    var reharvistable = Bool()
    var stages = [Stage]()
}

struct Stage {
    var minDay = Int()
    var maxDay = Int()
    var minWater = Int()
    var maxWater = Int()
}
```

Then you could define a crop like this:

```
Crops.append(Crop(name: "Turnip", season:" spring", reharvistable: false, stages: [
    Stage(minDay: 2, maxDay: 3, minWater: 2, maxWater: 7),
    ...
])
```

This way you can have as many stages as you'd like, and add or remove them at will.